# Could not found the main class. Program will exist - while executing runnable jar

Tags: java, executable-jar

I created a executable jar on a machine jre1.6 installed. The desktop version is working fine with my machine. When this installed in a server, while executing the .jar it shows the error:

> Could not found the main class. Program will exist.

I have googled this, mostly this error message was due to JRE version difference, where it is built and it is used.

I didn't get the details for jre version of server. Are there any other source in which this error occurs other than for JRE versions?

*Note:* The executable jar works fine, I have given the source class in the Manifest.mf. The application was launced through a .exe, through which execuatble jar runs.

Comment: You can fire "java -version" in cmd to get the java version. Please compare the version in both environment.

Comment: Does it show *any* more information than just that single line? How exactly are you running it?

Comment: The Error showned in Alert box. I ran it by executing .exe, which calls the .jar file with a .properties file to execute.

Comment: Meanwhile i tried compiling with jre7, and ran in jre6 installed machine.
I thought it will not run as the version used to compile was higher, but it actually ran fine.

So not all .jars compiled with higer version of jre had issue while executing in a machine which has lower jre versions??

Comment: So this is what the problem. The application complied with jre1.6 not compatible in jvm1.5. It not able to get the main method which i had specified in manifest.mf.

Solution is to update the running environment to jvm1.6.
Else need to compile the application for lower version, build it and export the 'App Client JAR' (1.5). Need to make sure the code should compile for older version without error.